# Deserialize entire FlowDocument issue

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have the following string

```
<FlowDocument xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"><Paragraph>Some text <LineBreak /><LineBreak /> <Run FontWeight="bold">Text ...</Run><LineBreak />sjhfdjsgfjsd <LineBreak /><LineBreak /> <Run FontWeight="bold">Text 2 </Run><LineBreak />sdkfskfjsf <LineBreak /><LineBreak /> </Paragraph></FlowDocument>
```

And I try to use this code to deserialize it into FlowDocument but no success.

Any clue what I am missing?

Thank you!

**CODE**

```
 StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xamlString);
 XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
 Section sec = XamlReader.Load(xmlReader) as Section;
 FlowDocument doc = new FlowDocument();
 while (sec.Blocks.Count > 0)
   doc.Blocks.Add(sec.Blocks.FirstBlock);
 return doc;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.I found it.

```
 var stringReader = new StringReader(xamlString);
 var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
 var doc= XamlReader.Load(xmlReader) as FlowDocument;
```